# File is not being downloaded in the specified downloads path in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a scraping project where sometimes visiting an URL downloads file automatically. For that I have specified the fixed download path like below -

```py
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": "/home/user/Documents/project/downloads"}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

This used to work like a week ago, but today the file always gets downloaded to current directory instead of the specified path. What could be causing this to happen? Am I missing something :(

You can try [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sites/default/files/software-lifecycle/ibm_software_lifecycle_product_list.csv) URL as an example.

Thanks

Comment: Use `request` to download the file. See [downloading file using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/14900791).

Comment: There is no issue with file being downloaded. Selenium is downloading file properly. The issue is - its not being downloaded in the `right folder` but instead in the current directory.